# Why isn't this valid XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, content-management-system

I'm trying to put a block of HTML into a field in a content management system, but it keeps stripping out one of the elements. In particular it is stripping out the `<i class="sprite arrowDDnav"></i>` from the block below.

```
<a class="static selected menu-item rootActive" href="/community/presbyterian-healthcare-foundation/Pages/default.aspx">
    <i class="sprite arrowDDnav"></i>
    <span class="additional-background">
        <span class="menu-item-text">Presbyterian Healthcare Foundation</span>
        <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Any idea why this might be? And any idea how I can "trick" the CMS into preserving the above HTML, or should I resort to using JQuery and `document.ready(...)` to inject the element in the appropriate place?

Comment: Which CMS are we talking about?

Comment: @aaronk6 It's not a commercial one

Comment: But you won’t tell us?

Comment: I could take a stab in the dark and ponder that this a case of the CMS being clever and removing the contentless element. But of course, nobody can really tell you anything about how this CMS works.